# BASH manipulating text file into array

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I've got a text file `(clients)` that contains around 150 lines of information

Each line is similar to :

"2","USERID","ACCESSCODE"
**Eg:**

```
"1","545ghu","7687686686868709ioo98968g"
"1","G2567u","54564df76786470976476987w"
"1","Y5po97","iuioubhjgjg768b79j9890980"
```

I want to grep this file, only find entries containing G2 or Y5 in the second column, remove all Double quotes and send the result to an array.

I can do this with

`foo=( $(grep 'G2\|Y5' clients | sed 's/"//g') )`

This result in the array `foo` which contains entries like :

`foo[0]` =     `1,G2567u,54564df76786470976476987w`

What I'd like is the results in `foo` to look like this:

`G2567u (54564df76786470976476987w)`

Can someone advise how to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Your expected output looks strange due `(` and `)` and missing first number. What are you doing to do with this array?

Comment: `arr=( $(...) )` is an antipattern -- in general, you shouldn't ever do it. F/e, if one of the words emitted by your command substitution is `*`, you'll get a list of filenames in your array. Use `readarray`, `mapfile`, `read -a`, or a `while read` loop with `arr+=( "$item" )` instead.

Comment: I would rethink whether *any* of this should be done in `bash`, instead of a language with a proper CSV library and real data structures.

Comment: BTW, the data structure you're asking for is liable to be suboptimal. If your actual use case is, say, looking up the access code from the user ID, then you should have an [associative array](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Associative_Arrays) (what other languages might call a "dictionary" or "map") that maps the former to the latter.

Comment: My aim is to create a select menu of the result to allow us to select which USERID and Access code to use. Having the select options as `ID (Code)` is neater to view and the '1' etc isn't needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for any external command -- `awk`, `sed` *or* `grep` -- here; all the necessary primitives are available native to bash itself.

```
array=( )
while IFS='",' read -r num userid access_code _; do
  if [[ $userid =~ (G2|Y5) ]]; then
    array+=( "${userid} (${access_code})" )
  fi
done < clients
```

See:

- [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) -- *How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?*
- [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29) - On why `hosts=( $(aws ...) )` is an antipattern
- [The BashGuide on native regular expression matching](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns#Regular_Expressions-1)

Comment: It reads from stdin. You can read from a file named `clients` by putting `< clients` after the `done`, as you would redirect stdin for any other command.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` for text manipulation (and separation of concerns) with `readarray` to convert the output to `bash` array

to simplify parsing, set quote and comma as field delimiters, which will change the field index.

```
$ readarray ar < <(awk -F'[",]' '$5~/G2|Y5/{print $5,"("$8")"}' file)  

$ echo "${ar[0]}"
G2567u (54564df76786470976476987w)
```

also, perhaps you're looking for ***begins with*** instead of ***contains*** for the special values.  In that case to eliminate false positives change the condition to `$5~/^(G2|Y5)/`

Comment: do you mean `echo`?

Answer (score 0):

I try to use bash string slice, while loop to extract data into bash array.

```
declare -a arr

while IFS="\r\n" read -r line; do
    # replace "," to | as field delimiter
    line="${line//\",\"/|}"
    # remove "
    line="${line//\"/}"
    # remove first field via delimiter |
    line="${line#*|}"
    # extract userid
    userid="${line%%|*}"

    if [[ "${userid}" =~ (G2|Y5) ]]; then
        # extract access_code
        access_code="${line##*|}"
        # arr+=( "${userid} (${access_code})" )
        arr[${#arr[@]}]="${userid} (${access_code})"
    fi
done < <(echo "${clients}")
# done < /PATH/clients.txt

echo "${arr[@]}"
echo "${#arr[@]}"
```